# High resolution DEM for digital soil mapping and modelling

Tags: remote-sensing, soil

I am carrying out an exercise on digital mapping of soil properties. I have tried several high resolution DEMs like 90 m and 30 m but their resolution is not good enough. Kindly assist.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: check: http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=free+dem

Comment: Public and private libraries are different. it depends which country it is for, where you will find it! state country.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your area of interest. If you are just testing a method, one of the large coverage free DEMs with high resolution (2m) is ArcticDEM, but as its name say it covers the Arctic only (Alaska, Northern Canada, Northern Europe, Russia, etc.). You can check that one out ([ArcticDEM](https://www.pgc.umn.edu/data/arcticdem/))

This is the coverage of ArcticDEM
[image]

Comment: Probably not much soil to analyze in that region.

Comment: I just added a coverage picture, as you can see there is PLENTY of soil in that region.